# MySQL Get start and ending from Week()

Tags: mysql

So let's say

```
WEEK(Date,1)
```

returns `32`, how do I get it to give me date of the Monday of that week, so that it returns `2017-08-07`?

Comment: Didn't found anything related to my question

Comment: Didn't google very hard. Try 'sql how do i get it to give me the monday of that week'

Comment: found something, aint working

Comment: Stopping after you found something that didn't work is not (re)searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
select if(weekday('2017-08-05') != 0, 
case 
when weekday('2017-08-05') =6 then date_sub('2017-08-05', interval 6     
day) 
when weekday('2017-08-05') =5 then date_sub('2017-08-05', interval 5     
day)
when weekday('2017-08-05') =4 then date_sub('2017-08-05', interval 4     
day)
when weekday('2017-08-05') =3 then date_sub('2017-08-05', interval 3 
day)
when weekday('2017-08-05') =2 then date_sub('2017-08-05', interval 2 
day)
when weekday('2017-08-05') =1 then date_sub('2017-08-05', interval 1 
day) end,'2017-08-05') as Date_of_Monday;
```

Shall give you the date of 'Monday' of the week of the Date you give as input

For the above query,
I gave input as `2017-08-05` and it gave the result as `2017-07-31` which is the Monday of the week the date `2017-08-05` falls in.